# Reading file, storing in array, error: no match for 'operator>>'

Tags: c++, file, ofstream

I have a file weights01.txt which is filled with floats in a 4x3 matrix as below

```
1.1 2.123 3.4
4.5 5 6.5
7 8.1 9
1 2 3.1
```

I am trying to read this file and transfer the data to an array called newarray. This is the code I am using:

```
int main()
{
  ofstream myfile;
  float newarray[4][3];
  myfile.open ("weights01.txt");
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 4; i++)   // row loop
    {
        for(int j = 0 ; j < 3; j++)  // column loop
        {
            myfile >> newarray[i][j]; // store data in matrix
        }
    }
  myfile.close();
  return 0;
}
```

I get an error with the line

```
myfile >> newarray[i][j];
```

error: no match for 'operator>>' in 'myfile >> newarray[i][j]'

I do not understand why this error is occuring

I searched for previous questions about this "no match for 'operator>>' error including [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26154494/error-no-match-for-operator-in-myfile-sdclassopenconst-char-uint8-t) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28343893/error-no-match-for-operator-in-standard-operatorchar). I also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading/4421719#4421719) long discussion on overloading operators but I did not find an explanation (possibly because I have not used files much before and don't really follow what is happening.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot read from an `std::ofstream` (short for *out* file stream), it is for output only.
Use an `std::ifstream` (that is *in* file stream) instead.

If you should ever have questions about which standard library facility does what, check out your favorite reference, for example [cppr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/).

---

OT remark: You can directly construct the stream from the filename:

```
std::ifstream myfile ("weights01.txt");
```

and you need not `close()` the file when you are done, the stream's destructor will handle that for you.